# Django Channels ошибка отправки

Tags: django, python-3.5

[image: вот что в консоли]Прохожу туториал https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html
при нажатии кнопки "send" сообщение не отправляется
 я так понимаю проблема в пути но не пойму что именно.
Ошибка вот такая -  HTTP GET /chat/1/ 200 [0.01, 127.0.0.1:46746]
[Failure instance: Traceback: : No route found for path 'ws/chat/1/'.

chat/routing.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
   path('ws/chat/<str:room_name>/$', consumers.ChatConsumer),
```

]

chat/consumers.py

```
    from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
    import json

    class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
        def connect(self):
            self.accept()

        def disconnect(self, close_code):
            pass

        def receive(self, text_data):
            text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
            message = text_data_json['message']

            self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'message': message
            }))
```

chat/templates/chat/room.html

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <title>Chat Room</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <textarea id="chat-log" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea><br/>
            <input id="chat-message-input" type="text" size="100"/><br/>
            <input id="chat-message-submit" type="button" value="Send"/>
        </body>
        <script>
            var roomName = {{ room_name_json }};

            var chatSocket = new WebSocket(
                'ws://' + window.location.host +
                '/ws/chat/' + roomName + '/');

            chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
                var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
                var message = data['message'];
                document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += (message + '\n');
            };

            chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
                console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
            };

            document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').focus();
            document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode === 13) {  // enter, return
                    document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
                }
            };

            document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
                var messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
                var message = messageInputDom.value;
                chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                    'message': message
                }));

                messageInputDom.value = '';
            };
        </script>
        </html>
```

routing.py

```
    from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
    from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
    import chat.routing

    application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
        # (http->django views is added by default)
        'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
            )
        ),
    })
```

urls.py)

```
 from django.urls import path,include
 from django.contrib import admin

 urlpatterns = [
    path('chat/', include('chat.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 ]
```

Comment: Может, в основном `urls.py` что-то переопределено. Как именно Вы включаете `routing.py`?

Comment: Добавил код urls.py и routing.py

Comment: Попробуйте стереть доллар в routing.py

Comment: Спасибо!!!! 
Я в шоке...1.5 часа мозг ломал